# Как оптимизировать игру на Canvas JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

Появились трудности с созданием игры на чистом JS. Реализую собственную змейку) Да, я старомодный, но для меня это уже достижение.

В чем вопрос, я в массив добавляю хвост и первым элементом массива змейки является голова змейки. Когда я отрисовываю змейку, будь то через setInterval, или же через requestAnimation, при большом количестве точек хвоста, фпс значительно падает. Ребят, я хочу максимальную оптимизацию, спасайте )))

Код:

```js
const c = document.getElementById("ctx");

c.width = 700;
c.height = 500;

const ctx = c.getContext("2d");


function random(max, v = 0, ) {

  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  if (v === 1 && r % 5 !== 0 || r % 10 === 0 && v === 1) {
    r = random(max, 1)
  }

  return r;
}

function Snake() {
  this.Ox = 10, // Направление змейки
    this.Oy = 0;


  this.speed = 10;

  this.r = 5, // Радиус и длина змейки
    this.length = [{
      "x": 5,
      "y": 5,
      "color": "black"
    }];

  this.lastX,
    this.lastY;

  this.head = null;
}

Snake.prototype.add = function() {
  let num = this.length.length;
  this.length[num] = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "color": "silver"
  }
}

Snake.prototype.move = function() {

  if (this.length[0].x === c.width - this.r && this.Ox === this.speed) {
    this.Ox = 0;
  } else if (this.length[0].x === 0 + this.r && this.Ox === -this.speed) {
    this.Ox = 0;
  } else if (this.length[0].y === c.height - this.r && this.Oy === this.speed) {
    this.Oy = 0;
  } else if (this.length[0].y === 0 + this.r && this.Oy === -this.speed) {
    this.Oy = 0;
  }
  // for (let i = 0; i < this.length.length; i++) {
  //     if (i !== 0) {
  //         if (this.length[0].x === this.length[i].x && this.length[0].y === this.length[i].y) {
  //             this.Oy = 0;
  //             this.Ox = 0;
  //         }
  //     }
  // }
  for (let i = this.length.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (i === 0) {
      this.length[i].x += this.Ox;
      this.length[i].y += this.Oy;
    } else {
      this.length[i].x = this.length[i - 1].x;
      this.length[i].y = this.length[i - 1].y;
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = this.length[i].color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.length[i].x, this.length[i].y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    ctx.fill();
  }
}



let s = new Snake();

let x = random(c.width, 1, s.length),
  y = random(c.height, 1, s.length);

function direction(l = 0, r = 0, u = 0, d = 0) {
  if (l === 1) {
    if (s.Ox === 0) {
      s.Ox = -s.speed;
    }
    s.Oy = 0;
  } else if (r === 1) {
    if (s.Ox === 0) {
      s.Ox = s.speed;
    }
    s.Oy = 0;
  } else if (u === 1) {
    if (s.Oy === 0) {
      s.Oy = -s.speed;
    }
    s.Ox = 0;
  } else if (d === 1) {
    if (s.Oy === 0) {
      s.Oy = s.speed;
    }
    s.Ox = 0;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 83:
      direction(0, 0, 0, 1);
      break;
    case 87:
      direction(0, 0, 1, 0);
      break;
    case 65:
      direction(1, 0, 0, 0);
      break;
    case 68:
      direction(0, 1, 0, 0);
      break;
    case 82:
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        s.add()
      }
  }
})

function bot() {
  if (s.length[0].x < x) {
    if (s.Ox === -s.speed) {
      direction(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    direction(0, 1, 0, 0);
  }
  if (s.length[0].x > x) {
    if (s.Ox === s.speed) {
      direction(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }
    direction(1, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  if (s.length[0].y > y) {
    if (s.Oy === -s.speed) {
      direction(0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
    direction(0, 0, 1, 0);
  }
  if (s.length[0].y < y) {
    if (s.Ox === s.speed) {
      direction(0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
    direction(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}


function apple() {
  if (s.length[0].x === x && s.length[0].y === y) {
    x = random(c.width, 1);
    y = random(c.height, 1);

    s.add();
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length.length; i++) {
    if (s.length[0].y === x && s.length[0].x === y) {
      x = random(max, 1);
      y = random(c.height, 1);
    }
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill();
}

// setInterval(() => {
//     ctx.fillStyle = "white";
//     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
//     apple()
//     bot();
//     s.move();
// }, 40);

function anim() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    apple()
    bot();
    s.move();
    anim();
  });

}
anim();
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: большое количество точек это какое? Вроде в вопросе не заметно понижение

Comment: `ctx.fillStyle = "white"; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);` — заново рисуете всё. А у змейки по сути меняется только хвост и голова ( -1 / +1 ), а всё тело остается неизменным... поэтому можно стирать только хвостик и добавить +1 в сторону головы, а тело не трогать. Ну и вдобавок → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205828/html5-canvas-performance-and-optimization-tips-tricks-and-coding-best-practices/8485927 там собраны все полезные фишки.

Comment: а мне понравилось -плюсик в репу от меня

Comment: Если что, змейка может врезаться в себя. Там есть закомментированный код. Максимальное количество 1000 мячиков, после чего начинает замедляться

Comment: В классической змейке один элемент из хвоста переносится перед головой (в зависимости от направления движения). Вы каждый раз перерисовываете всю картину, а можно очищать зону последнего круга хвоста, и отрисовывать голову. Используйте `clearRect`, попробуйте не строить каждый раз геометрию круга, а держать в кэше отрисованный кругляш серого и черного цветов на другом (невидимом канвас) и вызывать метод `drawImage()`. Если каждый раз еще массив только пушить, а не перестраивать его весь, то есть держать указатели на хвост, то должно работать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в будущем, для каждого из мячика будет назначено отдельное свойство. Я хочу создать игру на базе змейки с дополнительными возможностями Будем считать, что каждый мячик должен иметь собственный цвет, и удаление последнего нарушит строение змейки

Comment: Думаю, вычисления на построение геометрии, сглаживание и прочее в любом случае жрет много вычислительных ресурсов. Попробуйте круги разных цветов отрисовывать отдельно, вроде спрайта. Возможно, лучше каждый в отдельности отрисовать, я рисовал до 10000 canvas без вставки их в DOM, отлично все быстро работает. Пробуйте оптимизировать еще: `c.width` , возможно каждый раз делает get запрос к узлу DOM, присвойте значение переменной и всё! `let wid = c.width = 700`. Есть и много другого здесь для оптимизации.

Comment: Ну еще можно попробовать следующее. Можно представить все поле в виде сетки и разделить на два слоя. Первый видимый слой представляет из себя сетку из круглых окошечек, белый фон. Этот слой отрисовывается один раз. Задний фон должен представлять из себя крупную сетку из "пикселей" (квадратов со стророной = радиус), на этом слое отключить все сглаживания и т.д. Задний слой меняется. Ему передается схема с координатами пикселей и они отрисовываются в виде цветных квадратов-пикселей. Вроде есть методы для "увеличения" пикселя до нужного размера, тогда операции будут предельно дешевыми.

Comment: Да! В этой статье аппаратное масштабирование берете для заднего слоя и все. Тогда всего то 70X50 будет размер canvas))